# How to locate consecutive NANs in the beginning/end of a pandas datetime-series

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, missing-data

I have a time series mapping each day to the number of steps walked.  I would like to fill missing values one way if they appear consecutively in the beginning of the date-range I am examining.  (And otherwise if they are in the "middle" of the data or at the end).  Is there a way similar to str.startswith for identifying these consecutive NANs?

Here's an example:

original dataset:

```
               ID  Steps
Day                     
2019-07-25  53668    0.0
2019-07-26  53668    0.0
2019-07-27  53668    0.0
2019-07-28  53668  100.0
2019-07-29  53668    0.0
2019-07-30  53668    0.0
2019-07-31  53668    0.0
2019-08-01  53668  100.0
2019-08-02  53668    0.0
2019-08-03  53668    0.0
2019-08-04  53668    0.0
2019-08-05  53668    0.0

idx = pd.date_range('2019-07-20','2019-08-03')
df.reindex(idx, fill_value = np.nan)
```

yields:

```
                 ID  Steps
2019-07-20      NaN    NaN
2019-07-21      NaN    NaN
2019-07-22      NaN    NaN
2019-07-23      NaN    NaN
2019-07-24      NaN    NaN
2019-07-25  53668.0    0.0
2019-07-26  53668.0    0.0
2019-07-27  53668.0    0.0
2019-07-28  53668.0  100.0
2019-07-29  53668.0    0.0
2019-07-30  53668.0    0.0
2019-07-31  53668.0    0.0
2019-08-01  53668.0  100.0
2019-08-02  53668.0    0.0
2019-08-03  53668.0    0.0
```

How do I know that the 28 NaNs here are at the beginning and not interspersed, or at the end?

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: The expected output would be the dataframe with rows July 20th-24th or just the dates (as indices)
and then I can fill the missing id values with 53668 and the steps with zeros.  But if the NaN's would be in the middle I would impute with the mean instead of zero

Comment: Can you edit question, because bad format of comments?

Comment: So if missing values in start or end of data are repalced 0, if in middle are replace by mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there si no such function.

You need write it:

```
#change data for NaNs in middle
print (df)
               ID  Steps
Day                     
2019-07-25  53668    0.0
2019-07-26  53668    0.0
2019-07-27  53668    0.0
2019-07-28  53668  100.0
2019-07-31  53668    0.0
2019-08-01  53668  100.0
2019-08-02  53668    0.0
2019-08-03  53668    0.0
2019-08-04  53668    0.0
2019-08-05  53668    0.0
```

---

```
idx = pd.date_range('2019-07-20','2019-08-08')
df = df.reindex(idx, fill_value = np.nan)
print (df)
                 ID  Steps
2019-07-20      NaN    NaN
2019-07-21      NaN    NaN
2019-07-22      NaN    NaN
2019-07-23      NaN    NaN
2019-07-24      NaN    NaN
2019-07-25  53668.0    0.0
2019-07-26  53668.0    0.0
2019-07-27  53668.0    0.0
2019-07-28  53668.0  100.0
2019-07-29      NaN    NaN
2019-07-30      NaN    NaN
2019-07-31  53668.0    0.0
2019-08-01  53668.0  100.0
2019-08-02  53668.0    0.0
2019-08-03  53668.0    0.0
2019-08-04  53668.0    0.0
2019-08-05  53668.0    0.0
2019-08-06      NaN    NaN
2019-08-07      NaN    NaN
2019-08-08      NaN    NaN
```

---

```
m = df['ID'].isna()
first = df['ID'].ffill().isna()
last = df['ID'].bfill().isna()

print (df[first])

2019-07-20 NaN    NaN
2019-07-21 NaN    NaN
2019-07-22 NaN    NaN
2019-07-23 NaN    NaN
2019-07-24 NaN    NaN

print (df[last])
            ID  Steps
2019-08-06 NaN    NaN
2019-08-07 NaN    NaN
2019-08-08 NaN    NaN

print (df[~(first | last) & m])
            ID  Steps
2019-07-29 NaN    NaN
2019-07-30 NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Apologies for the late response.  Thank you very much!  This was exactly what i wanted.  Now that I have the mask I can apply fillna according to the relevant mask.  Thank you!